# TypeError:Return value of CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main::getConfiguredAutoRenewOptionForMembershipType() must be of the type int,null returned

Tags: upgrade, drupal-7

***Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.69.2, PHP 7.4, Smarty 2.***

While trying to access a contribution page at /civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=9 got an unexpected:

```
> TypeError: Return value of CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main::getConfiguredAutoRenewOptionForMembershipType()
> must be of the type int, null returned in CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main->getConfiguredAutoRenewOptionForMembershipType()
> (line 1863 of /srv/www/public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "auto-renew" option has been cleaned up for all membership types while the latest upgrade, not sure why. Had to re-enable for each membership type at civicrm/admin/member/membershipType?reset=1